# ELF File Format

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, simulation, elf, spim

I'm attempting to manually load the hexdump of an elf file that I compiled using g++ into a processor simulation I designed. There are 30 sections to a standard elf file and I am loading all 30 segments with their proper memory location offset taken into account. I then start my program counter at the beginning of the `.text` section (00400130) but it seems that the program isn't running correctly. I have verified my processor design relatively thoroughly using SPIM as a gold standard. The strange thing is that, if I load an assembly file into SPIM, and then take the disassembled `.text` and `.data` sections that are generated by the software, load them into my processor's memory, the programs work. This is different from what I want to do because I want to:

- write a c++ program
- compile it using mipseb-linux-g++ (cross compiler)
- hex dump all sections into their own file
- read files and load contents into processor "memory"
- run program

Where in the ELF file should I place my program counter initially? I have it at the beginning of `.text` right now. Also, do I only need to include `.text` and `.data` for my program to work correctly? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Also, are there any commands that will dump the entire binary (addresses 0 - eof) in the same format as readelf's?

Comment: `objcopy -S input output` will get rid of all the linker / debug stuff you don't care about, and generates a file (`output`) of the same format as its input argument (`input`).

Comment: You may have done this, but if you haven't, then you should verify that the sections you load, after you load them, contain the data that you think they should.  If you can view memory in your processor simulation, then you should create a binary representation of one of your sections (`objcopy -O binary -j .text input output.bin`), and compare the contents of memory with the data in (in this example) `output.bin`.

Comment: I've verified that my memory mapping works correctly.  I can just output all allotted memory elements with each location.  That seems to work fine.  I get the offset for each section in the same way I acquire the PC start point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ELF header should include the entry address, which is not necessarily the same as the first address in the `.text` region.  Use `objdump -f` to see what the entry point of the file is -- it'll be called the "start address".

The format is described [here](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf) - you should be using the `program headers` rather than the `section headers` for loading the ELF image into memory (I doubt that there are 30 program headers), and the entry point will be described by the `e_entry` field in the ELF header.

Comment: Good to know.  Turns out the starting address just happens to be 400130 for this format.  Well, I know I'm starting at the correct location anyway.  To run a program do I need to include any other sections other than text and data?  Perhaps rodata?  I'm not sure.

Comment: If you use the program headers (which you should be doing, as you care about the "execution view" of the ELF file, rather than the "linker view"), the sections aren't named.  But yes, there are other sections you'll care about.  Take a look at the output from `objdump -h` - any sections that include ALLOC or LOAD probably need to be loaded into memory.  I'm not completely sure that's the case, because I use the program headers, rather than the section headers, for loading ELF images.

Comment: `objdump -p` will tell you what the program headers are for the image.

Comment: You'll need `.rodata`; that's most likely where constant static objects end up. You'll need to allocate memory for the `.bss` (uninitialised data) sections; they're not included in the file. There are a few other code sections as well as `.text` that might be present: `.ctors`, `.dtors`, `.init`, `.fini`.

Comment: What are the headers for? (I'm not particularly familiar with ELF format)

Comment: I suggest reading the document I linked to.  Quoting: "A program header table, if present, tells the system how to create a process image. Files used to build a process image (execute a program) must have a program header table; relocatable files do not need one. A section header table contains information describing the file’s sections. Every section has an entry in the table; each entry gives information such as the section name, the section size, etc. Files used during linking must have a section header table; other object files may or may not have one."  It also describes .bss, .data, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use the e_entry field of the ELF header to determine where to set the Program Counter.

Comment: Apparently I was setting my PC to the correct location.  Previously I was just loading my .text section first and automatically determining my PC start point by referencing the first address in the dump file.  I can use this to get the correct value in a more assured manner.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `Elf32_Ehdr.e_entry` (or `Elf64_Ehdr.e_entry` if you are on 64-bit platform). You should at least also include the `.bss` section, which is empty, but has "in-memory" size in the disk ELF image.

Wikipedia will lead you to all [necessary documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elf_format).

#### Edit:

Here's from `objdump -h /usr/bin/vim` on my current box:

```
Sections:
Idx Name         Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
...
22 .bss          00009628  00000000006df760  00000000006df760  001df760  2**5
                 ALLOC
23 .comment      00000bc8  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  001df760  2**0
                 CONTENTS, READONLY
```

Note the `File off` is the same for both `.bss` and `.comment`, which means `.bss` is empty in the disk file, but should be `0x9628` bytes in memory.

Comment: My .bss section isn't empty actually.  What could this mean?    Also,  I'm using a c++ map to represent my memory so any location that isn't assigned a value will default to "0".

Comment: How do you know it's not empty?

Comment: when I run "readelf -x 15 helloworld" the section has elements at many locations.  As dense as .text.

Comment: Oh, never mind, it is quite empty.  I must have referenced the wrong section.

Comment: `objdump` numbers sections from 0, while `readelf` counts them from 1. Look for the heading `Hex dump of section '.XXXX':` - is that `.bss`?

Comment: You need to allocate section in memory if it's marked `ALLOC`, and load it from file if marked `LOAD`.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Technically any arbitrary elements are allocated in memory (assuming that an empty element's contents is "0").